# Can I login to my stencil theme I am developing for bigcommerce?

Tags: bigcommerce

I am working on a stencil theme, (first one), just using the default Cornerstone Light theme they supply you with. I am wondering if its possible to login to my local version of the theme at the `http://localhost:3000` to alter pages and nav menus. My default login credentials for my bigcommerce store don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to login to the store online and it will sync with the local version. It isn't a complete BigCommerce VM, so it lacks the ability to support local merchant login (but does support customer login).

Comment: Perfect answer, it updated my nav accordingly thanks!